# Hbase master not running in pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run Hbase in a pseudo-distributed mode. I followed the link http://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/installing-pseudo-distributed-hbase-on-ubuntu/

I am using ubuntu version 12.04
Hbase version 0.94.8
Hadoop Version 2.4.0

In hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh, i added the following

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25

```
export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/conf/regionservers

export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Then I set the HBASE_HOME path in bashrc file

In   hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
I added the following,

```
<configuration>

<property>

<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>

</property>



<property>

<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>

<value>true</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>

<value>localhost</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>dfs.replication</name>

<value>1</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>

<value>2181</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>/home/prashasti/Installed/hbase-0.94.8/HBASE/zookeeper</value>

</property>

</configuration>
```

To prevent version mismatch between hadoop and hbase, I added

```
hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
```

and

```
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.0.jar in hbase/lib folder
```

When I start hbase using

```
$./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

No error turns up, but the Hmaster doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

This question is bit old. I am answering so that it might help someone else...

The problem appears to be a mismatch between Hadoop version and HBase version. Changing the jars inside hbase/lib folder will not help as those jars are only used in standalone mode.

You need to recompile HBase as specified here http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#basic.prerequisites